# ¿Qué método puedo usar para combinar un setColor JPanel con Setcolor Jlabel?

Tags: java, java-swing

Quiero hallar un metodo o una combinación con la linea de mi codigo buscando una función hover de que cuando yo presione el Jpanel se lleve consigo mismo el Jlabel junto, tambien quiero hacer lo mismo con los iconos pero en este caso desconozco mucho, pienso que deberia cambiar la imagen en su misma posición al hacer pressed con el Jpanel.

```
    `//color jpanel
    setColor(btnInicio2);       
    resetColor(btnCliente2);
    resetColor(btnProveedor2);
    resetColor(btnProductos2);
    resetColor(btnFacturacion2);
    resetColor(btnImprimir2);

    //color label
    setLblColor(Lbl_inicio);
    resetLblColor(Lbl_clientes);
    resetLblColor(Lbl_proveedor);
    resetLblColor(Lbl_productos);
    resetLblColor(Lbl_facturacion);
    resetLblColor(Lbl_registro);

    //SOMBREADO DE LOS PANEL DEL MENU
private void setColor(JPanel pane) 
{
    pane.setBackground(new Color(89, 106, 158)); //64,112,244 57,76,135
}

private void resetColor(JPanel pane) {
        pane.setBackground(new Color(57,76,135)); //9,29,52
}

//COLOR DEL LOS LABEL DEL MENU
public void setLblColor(JLabel lbl) {
    lbl.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));
}

public void resetLblColor(JLabel lbl) {
    lbl.setForeground(new Color(166, 166, 166));// 166, 166, 166
}`
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1][image] adjunto una imagen del avance que llevo hasta ahora y de lo que quiero lograr con el codigo

Comment: butterfly! que diga, pon un [mcve] para poder reproducir facilmente tu problema, y por mientras te recomiendo que revises la documentacion de MouseAdapter